# Better way to write this Regex? Negative Lookahead

Tags: php, regex

I think I've got this working for the most part, but was wondering if there is a better way to write it:

```
/\b(Word)(?!.*?<\/a>)(?!.*?>)\b/
```

I'm trying to match Word when it's NOT linked, and it's NOT part of HTML tags (like `<a href="" title="Word">` should not match).

From what I understand, it's better to use negated character classes if possible rather than making it lazy. I tried doing that but couldn't figure it out. I don't even know if it's possible with this, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: Why try to fix what isn't broken?  If it's matching things fine (and you've tried matching it to some NEAR matches just to make sure), then I'd say just go with it.  What you're asking for could be written dozens of different ways, subject to personal preference.

Comment: Have you considered not trying to use regex for this, but instead actually parsing the HTML and then looking for the word in text elements that don't have link elements as parents?

Comment: @DerrickTucker You make a good point. I'm kind of new to coding and a bit of a perfectionist, but if it works, it might as well be used.

Comment: @Amber I honestly don't know much about parsing HTML. Are there any resources you could steer me toward? Thanks!

Comment: @AdamCapriola http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ is a useful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negated character class you are looking for is `[^<>]*`. That will skip any tag boundaries.

```
 /\b(Word) (?! [^<>]*<\/a> | [^<]*>) \b/x
```

Note that looking for `</a>` will allow the regex to match should the link have further markup in it; for example a bolded `<a>..<b>Word</b>..</a>` word would not be skipped. (Checking for such things requires far more effort than a lookahead.)

Comment: Thanks mario, that's excellent!! And thanks for the heads up about the more complicated example. Luckily, I doubt I'll run into problems like that. :)